# How to search an email from all folders in store using Linq Outlook C#

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am performing custom action on all incoming replies through VSTO add-in. The add-in will compare ConversationID of incoming reply with existing email. It works fine if I have to search inside one folder but my problem is email can be in any folder in store. Here is my code.

```
void items_ItemAdd(object Item)
        {
            Outlook.Application application = new Outlook.Application();
            string filter = "RE: ";
            Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;
            Outlook.Folder folder = mail.Parent as Outlook.Folder;
            if (Item != null)
            {
                if (mail.MessageClass == "IPM.Note" && mail.Subject.ToUpper().Contains(filter.ToUpper()))
                {
                    var RequiredMail = (from e in folder.Items.Cast<Outlook.MailItem>().OrderBy(X => X.ReceivedTime).Where(C => C.ConversationID == mail.ConversationID) select mail).FirstOrDefault();

                    // Perform custom action
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Also, I have read that searching for an email using Linq is not very efficient. Is there any other more efficient way to get `RequiredMail`?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51048663/c-sharp-interop-outlook-find-messages-with-specific-word-in-subject work?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must be aware that `ItemAdd` event may not be fired if more than sixteen items are added to the collection. This is a known issue in Outlook. The following series of articles describes possible workarounds for that:

- [Outlook NewMail event unleashed: the challenge (NewMail, NewMailEx, ItemAdd)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/03/outlook-newmail-event/)
- [Outlook NewMail event: solution options](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/24/outlook-newmail-solution-options/)
- [Outlook NewMail event and Extended MAPI: C# example](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/01/outlook-newmail-extended-mapi/)
- [Outlook NewMail unleashed: writing a working solution (C# example)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/10/outlook-newmail-custom-solution/)

Mixing LINQ and COM objects is not a really good idea. You should release underlying COM objects instantly to prevent any known issues.

If you need to search for items in all folders you may use the `AdvancedSearch` method of the Application class which allows to perform a search based on a specified DAV Searching and Locating (DASL) search string.

The key benefits of using the [AdvancedSearch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb219884(v=office.12)) method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular Items collection (see the Items property of the Folder class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the Store class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

Read more about that in the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article.

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed answer. One question, does advanced search work with filter `string filter = "urn:schemas:mailheader:conversationID LIKE \'%" + conversationID + "%\'";` ? Thank you.

Comment: String properties are supported. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb147583%28v%3doffice.12%29